# Is it possible to show request object's schema in swashbuckle.netcore 's UI next to the request object?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We use swashbuckle.netcore in our project, it is nice to see schema next to the response object's example.

[image]

However, the request part only contains an example, but not schema next to it (the request object's schema is listed at the bottom, which is really hard to find when the API become big).

Is there a way to show request object's schema next to the example or a link that can jump to the request object's schema at bottom of the page?

[image]